# how to pass object to handlebars view in express app

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I can not figure how to display data passed to handlabars view.
here is my route.js file, which passes object to view.

```
var session = require('express-session');
exports.admin = function(req, res){
    db.query("SELECT * FROM users", function(err, result, field){
       if(err) throw err;
       console.log(result);
       console.log(typeof result);
       res.render('page', {user: result});
     });
};
```

and here is my page.hbs file(view)

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>View Details</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {{#each user}}
<td>{{this}}</td>
 {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tbody>
    {{#each user}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{details}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

firstname, lastname, details are the properties of each user object

Comment: muito obrigado. fazia dias e horas q estava procurando.